# How can I add foregroundServiceType to a library manifest while maintaining backwards compatibility?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-10.0

My library project has a location service, and per Android Q requirements it sets the `android:foregroundServiceType="location"` attribute in the manifest. When an app module uses my library and compiles against API level 28, it fails with the following error:

```
AndroidManifest.xml:57: AAPT: error: attribute android:foregroundServiceType not found.
```

How can my library maintain compatibility with older versions, while making sure the functionality works on Android Q?

Comment: Everybody should be using the latest `compileSdkVersion`. Having that attribute in the manifest for your library does not affect runtime backwards compatibility, which is the more critical bit.

Comment: @CommonsWare I want to avoid breaking anyone's automatic builds. I was hoping there would be a way to avoid forcing developers to update the SDK they compile against.

Comment: You could distribute two libraries, one for those targeting Q+ and one for those targeting older devices, where this manifest attribute only appears in the former. You would want to then check `PackageManager` in the older-target library to confirm that the app really is targeting < 29, and fail fast at runtime if not. But if you want just one library, then that manifest attribute will be needed, and apps using your library will either need an up-to-date `compileSdkVersion` or to add manifest-merger stuff to remove your attribute.

Comment: what do you mean by location service ?? Are you requesting for location updates using FusedLocationProviderClient in a foreground service ??  What happens if we don't use this attribute android:foregroundServiceType="location" in manifest file ??

Comment: @PradeepkumarReddy I mean a service that requests locations. It does not necessarily have to be using `FusedLocationProviderClient`. Without setting this attribute, your app will not receive updated locations with the "while in use" permission. You should read the Android documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My goal is to avoid breaking anyone's build when the library version is updated, and at the same time avoid forcing the developer to compile against API 29. It seems I have two choices:

- Provide a separate library so that developers compiling against API 28 and lower don't get impacted;
- warn developers targeting the new version to replace the service definition in the manifest using `tools:node="replace"`.

The problem with the first approach is that I will need to maintain two libraries for some time. The problem with the second is that developers must remember to revert the change once they update the SDK version.

In my case, I will go with the second approach. By passing an explicit foreground service type to the `startForeground` method when targeting Android Q, I can cause a crash if the type is not set in the manifest. The developer can therefore catch this when targeting Android Q and revert the manifest change to fix it.

Comment: where di you add tools:node="replace" to? I have added it to my library moudle's service but it still gets the error.

Comment: @PandaWorld Did you add the `android:foregroundServiceType="location"` attribute as well? `tools:node="replace"` is meant to replace the service definition imported from the library with one you define in your app. It doesn't eliminate the need to define the `android:foregroundServiceType` attribute.

Answer (score 13):

I had same error and after migrating to `Androidx` and updating `compileSdkVersion` from 28 to 29 my issue was resolved. So please do these changes and you can get your solution